# slice assignment goes wrong in numpy array while in a "for" recurrent

Tags: python, numpy, slice

I find something wrong with python numpy.I want to use slices assignment to get a new numpy array.Just as the pictures shows:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9nwNf.png)

When I use slices assignment in "for" recurrent,such as:

```
v = np.array([[0,1],[2,3],[3,4],[7, 8])    
s = v[:2]
for i in range(1):
  s[1] = v[2]
```

The result show that the value of "v" changes in the assignment.

The result is different from below(just discard the "for" recurrent):

```
s[1] = v[2]
```

I'm crazy about this problem and I even doubt something wrong with numpy!!!
Wish help from someone!

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please add some reproducible code, formatted correctly. Your question will likely then become much clearer.

Comment: [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to create a good example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: `v[:2]` is a view, not a copy, when `v` is a NumPy array.

Answer (score -1):

Since you assign `s` a part of `v` it is actually not a copy but just a reference to `v`. This means if you change `s` you also change `v`.

What you can do in python is create a explicit copy of a datastructure to be sure that it is not a reference (https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html).

In your example it would like this:

```
from copy import deepcopy

v = np.array([[0,1],[2,3],[3,4],[7, 8]])    
s = deepcopy(v[:2])
for i in range(1):
    s[1] = v[2]
```

Result with deepcopy:

```
>>> s
array([[0, 1],
       [3, 4]])
>>> v
array([[0, 1],
       [2, 3],
       [3, 4],
       [7, 8]])
```

Result without deepcopy:

```
>>> s
array([[0, 1],
       [3, 4]])
>>> v
array([[0, 1],
       [3, 4],
       [3, 4],
       [7, 8]])
```